# How to check if PUSH notifications are enabled for my MAUI app on the device (Android, iOS)

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, permissions, maui

I am developing an application on MAUI, I use Firebase for PUSH notifications.
I was wondering how on startup it is possible to check if the user has disabled notification permissions or not for Android and iOS?

I searched for information, but did not find anything specific. I would be grateful if there is any documentation or samples regarding my question

Upd: Found this article and redid the notification check with it
https://dev.to/vhugogarcia/app-settings-in-net-maui-notifications-47mp

Comment: In general: [Checking Maui Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/permissions#checking-permissions). . For Android 13 may also need: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12291#issuecomment-1364590030

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Available permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/permissions?tabs=android#available-permissions), the Permission for Notifications hasn't been added to the [Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.applicationmodel.permissions?view=net-maui-7.0) in .NET MAUI.

And there's a feature request: [Permission for Notifications #12291](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12291) that being tracked in the link below, you can follow up there.

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12291

If the Permission for Notifications has been implemented in .NET MAUI, you probably can check the current status of it by below code:

```
PermissionStatus status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.Notifications>();
```